# Timestamp in Excel...not working?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, date-time

I know this question has been asked numerous times, and I have truly searched and attempted to work it out with the given solutions to no avail. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know much about VBA, so I don't know exactly what is wrong. 
Basically, I have values I am inputting into column E, and I want a timestamp to automatically update in column G once the respective value in E is modified.

I have used the following code from this website http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/timestamp.html:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        With Target
            If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Not Intersect(Range("A2:A10"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
                Else
                    With .Offset(0, 1)
                        .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                        .Value = Now
                    End With
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

I have attempted to modify it to fit my query, but when I enter a value in column G, nothing appears in column E. Can anyone explain how I can make this work?

Thank you

Comment: In the VBA window, select F8.  Thus will put VBA into a step mode.  Go back and change a value in column G.  You'll see the function exits at the very beginning.

Comment: @wbeard52 I'll try that. Quick question: In the code above, it says Offset(0,1), does this need to be changed based on my worksheet? I'm not sure what it means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code monitors column A, cells A2 to A10, not column E. It places the timestamp with an offset of 1 into the respective cells in column B.

If you want to monitor column E and enter the time stamp in column G then change the code to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
        With Target
            If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                    .Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
                Else
                    With .Offset(0, 2)
                        .NumberFormat = "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                        .Value = Now
                    End With
                End If
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have put in the code in the VBA window in Excel. Do I close out the window and it should work? I tried that but the timestamp didn't show up...

Comment: This code needs to go into the Sheet module of the sheet that you want it to run on. Right-click the sheet tab, click `View Code` and paste the code into the code window. Then close the VBE.